# How to show data from remote MySQL database in a MessageBox in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

I'm kinda new to C# and i'm currently just trying to connect to a remote SQL server which will then simply show the license key from the licensekeys table and show it in a MessageBox if it matches the license key in textBox1 all from the click of a button. (So basically like a login with a username and password except I just want a login with a license key)

What I have at the moment:

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source= MYSERVERIPHERE\\MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User ID=MYUSERID;Password=MYPASSWORD");
            SqlCommand = "SELECT licensekey FROM licensekeys WHERE licensekey = textBox1.Text";
```

Not sure what to do from here and would appreciate it if someone could guide me, cheers.

Comment: Which .net-version do you use? .net-Framework 4.x or .net-Core 1.x or .net-Core 2.0?

Comment: BTW you mix up SQL-Server(Microsoft) and MySQL. What do you want to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

If the connection works otherwise, the issue can be that the lisence key is TEXT field and the string needs to be inside apostrophes (c++ string as an example):

```
SqlCommand = "SELECT licensekey FROM licensekeys WHERE licensekey = '" + 
textBox1.Text + "'";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Data Source= MYSERVERIPHERE\\MSSQLSERVER2008;Initial Catalog=MYDB;User ID=MYUSERID;Password=MYPASSWORD");

SqlCommand = string.Format("SELECT licensekey FROM licensekeys WHERE licensekey = {0}" , textBox1.Text);
```

I am assuming that the connection string is correct and can really connect to the remote server

Answer (score 0):

Wait... before you copy and paste the answer to you code file, please note there is a vulnerability called SQL injection!!

For the MySQL connection string in C# you can search for it, or use a SQL connector developed by MySQL team or community out there
https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ , here is a example extracted from it:
`Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;`

And for the real code, I am sure that there is a `SQLCommand`, which you are using it already, and `SQLParameter` 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx to use, and it help you prevent SQL injection

Example: (assuming using SqlConnection works for MySQL, not sure; if it does not work, please use MySQL connector, and read corresponding docs)

```
var command = connect.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "SELECT licensekey FROM licensekeys WHERE licensekey = @license";
var license = new SQLParameter("@license", SqlDbType.Char) // let's assume the license only contains ASCII.
{
    Value = textBox1.Text
};
command.Parameters.Add(license);
command.ExecuteScalar(); // or command.ExecuteScalarAsync();, assuming you only want 1 row of record.
```

You will never want someone with license key `abc OR 1=1` and allow them to login to your system :(